# Xpath query that check whether 2 element text values exist in a list

Tags: xpath

I am trying to figure out a way to check whether 2 element text values exist in a list using Xpath query. I am limited to Xpath 1.0 at the moment.

I have a body of XML with a **subtree** that contains a list. It looks like this:

```
<tags>
      <tag>A</tag>
      <tag>B</tag>
      <tag>C</tag>
      <tag>E</tag>
</tags>
```

I want to have a query that returns a node-set if there are tag text values in that list that equal 'A' and 'C'.  (this runs a file with many of these xml tag lists I've described above.

This is my current best effort:

```
descendant-or-self::node()[local-name(.) = 'tag' and text() = 'A' and (preceding-sibling::text() = 'C' or following-sibling::text() = 'C')]
```

This issue is likely due to my nested condition and use of preceding-sibling and following-sibling.

Is is possible to nest conditions in the way?

Thanks in advance for any help and insights provided!

Answer (score 0):

if ( //tag/text() = 'A' and //tag/text() = 'C' ) then //tag[text() = 'A' or text() = 'C'] else //empty

Comment: I am not able to test this solution using xmllint --xpath "if ( //tag/text() = 'A' and //tag/text() = 'C' ) then //tag[text() = 'A' or text() = 'C'] else //empty" file.xml due to Xpath evaluation failure: Invalid expression.

Comment: You need XPath 2.0 to use if. You can test it online here: https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I failed to mention I am restricted to Xpath1.0 (edited my post to reflect this). I tested this with the XML file I am working with and was not able to successfully match my test case.

Comment: In case of XPath 1.0 this can help: https://dreamix.eu/blog/java/xml-java/how-to-create-if-else-statement-in-xpath-1-0

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I arrived at:

```
//descendant-or-self::node()[local-name(.) = 'tag' and text() = 'A' and (preceding-sibling::node()[text() = 'C'] or following-sibling::node()[text() = 'C']) ]
```